# unexpected filed error in nest js file upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, backend, multer

Hi I am not able to understand what is wrong with below method. it is throwing unexpected field error. even I have changed many files still it is same.

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
  console.log(file);
}
```

I am calling API using postman. Am I doing any mistake in postman?

[image]

Comment: `certificate.xlsx` is located in your local machine

Comment: Did you maybe forget to enter a `KEY`?

Comment: thank you . which key are you suggesting?

Comment: did you try to enter any KEY to your file in the request as was mentioned by @ChrisG? what was the result?

Comment: I didn't downvote but understand why someone did. Also, did you create a 2nd account to answer your own question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work like below.

[image]

you are selecting `file` but give some name as `key`. it is blank in your case.